# Access POD from another Perl 6 file

Tags: raku, pod6

The [Perl 6 POD documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pod#Accessing_Pod) has a section on accessing the current file's POD document by using `$=pod`. There is no information on accessing another file's POD document.

How can I access another file's POD structure, without altering the current file's `$=pod`?

Answer (score 4):

You can now do that with [Pod::Load](https://github.com/JJ/p6-pod-load). From [the `README` in the examples directory](https://github.com/JJ/p6-pod-load/blob/master/resources/examples/README.md)

```
  perl6 -e 'use Pod::Load; .perl.say for load("pod-load-clean.pod6")'
```

Please note that the Pod6 file has to be "clean", that is, not use any external module that is not generally available or it might fail.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a filesystem-agnostic solution in [Module::Pod](https://github.com/dmaestro/Module-Pod) (soon to be published) at git@github.com:dmaestro/Module-Pod.git

```
use Module::Pod;

# Get all Pod::Block::* objects in the module, from its own $=pod
my @pod = pod-from-module(<My::Module>);
```

Pros:

- No direct EVALS of file code (even within Module::Pod)
- Uses CompUnit::Repository and kin to locate the module
- May be used with or without `use`-ing the module for other purposes in your code
- If module is already loaded, you may call with its Type Object

Cons:

- Module uses nqp: methods directly, as in Pod::Convenience (maybe not really a con?)
- Not able to retrieve pod from *.pod files

Intended for use in Pod6-checking tests, etc.

Comment: Published to ecosystem and CPAN today.