# Obtaining the Pod of a module without explicitly exporting it

Tags: raku, precompiling, nqp, pod6

The [documentation in Perl 6 programs, using the Pod 6 DSL, are actually parsed as part of the code](http://blogs.perl.org/users/zoffix_znet/2018/01/perl-6-core-hacking-qastalicious.html); this makes that documentation available, inside the program, as the [`$=pod`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-%24%3D) variable.

However, I'd like to have access to that variable in order to process it from, say, tests. In [this example I wrote for the Perl 6 Advent Calendar](https://github.com/JJ/my-perl6-examples/blob/master/grammars/Santa-Letter.pm6) it's simply exported as a class (grammar, in this case) variable:

```perl6
our $pod = $=pod[0];
```

I can then use it this way:

```perl6
use Data::Dump;

use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;

sub MAIN( $module  ) {
    try require ::($module);
    say Dump( $::($module)::pod, :max-recursion(2) );

}
```

This works when called with the name of the class and the correct path; but it still needs the explicit export of the variable.

I have seen in [some code](https://github.com/perl6/doc/blob/master/lib/Pod/Convenience.pm6#L116-L132) that precomp stores can be used (sorry, no good single-source to explain these ones) for the same thing. Eventually, this line

```perl6
 return nqp::atkey($handle.unit,'$=pod')[0];
```

Does the trick, accessing the Pod of a module that is represented by the precomp store and contained in `$handle.unit`. The thing is that this is actually lower level, using the [`nqp::atkey`](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/master/docs/ops.markdown#atkey) operator of [NQP, not quite perl](https://github.com/perl6/nqp).

There are many ways of doing this, so I can think of two different possible questions.
1. Is there a way to access via a FQN (preceded by ::) the Pod of that `require`d or `use`d unit?
2. Do we have access to the precomp handle of a `require`d or `use`d unit so that we can call `nqp::atkey` directly?

Comment: Hi JJ. If you get a decent answer, maybe it will makes sense to add it, or at least a comment pointing to it, to [Access POD from another Perl 6 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990701/access-pod-from-another-perl-6-file).

Comment: @raiph done. I could then answer myself here, maybe...

Answer (score 3):

I used this technique (finding simpler ways to do it) to create [Module::Pod](https://github.com/dmaestro/Module-Pod) (soon to be published). See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57247392/332359